# Does the algebra of real valued functions in Stone-Weierstrass Thm. equal to the set of polynomials?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am studying Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. I wonder whether A is equal to the set of polynomials? If so, how can I proof this? And the statement is as follows:

> Let $S$ be a compact set, and let $A$ be an algebra of real valued functions on S. Assume that $A$ separates points and contains the constant functions. Then, the uniform closure of $A$ is equal to the algebra of all real continuous functions on $S$.

Comment: What do you mean by "in $R$, A is equal to the set of polynomials"?

Comment: Sorry. I mean that S is a compact set in R. ( Weierstrass theorem)

Answer (score 4):

The point is that the theorem works for any such algebra. That's why it extends the original result of Weierstrass.

If in particular $S\subset \mathbb R$, the theorem applies if you take $A$ to be the polynomials (because they separate points and contain the constant functions).

Comment: Now I see that this is an extension. Thank you so much.